# calculating the difference between two rows or alternative

Tags: sql

I would like to take this query (see below) and add a where win = in the select statement. here I would like to add a column to show the number of races it took to fulfill the where e.g below where win = 2

I've tried calculating the number between rows but it was wildly wrong on my part

```
select 
date, time, raceid, win

from master
where date = @date
order by time

DATE              TIME   RACEID WIN 
2019-01-06  00:40:00    4445    2   
2019-01-06  00:50:00    4432    0   
2019-01-06  01:00:00    4441    2   
2019-01-06  01:10:00    4446    2   
2019-01-06  01:20:00    4433    1   
2019-01-06  01:30:00    4439    1   
2019-01-06  01:40:00    4447    2   
2019-01-06  01:50:00    4434    2   
2019-01-06  02:00:00    4442    0   
2019-01-06  02:10:00    4448    0   
2019-01-06  02:20:00    4435    2   
2019-01-06  02:30:00    4443    2   
2019-01-06  02:40:00    4449    2   
2019-01-06  02:50:00    4436    0   
2019-01-06  02:50:00    4444    2
```

I would like to take this query and add a where win = in the select statement. here I would like to add a column to show the number of races it took to fulfill the where e.g below where win = 2

```
DATE              TIME   RACEID WIN RacestoWin
2019-01-06  00:40:00    4445    2     1
2019-01-06  01:00:00    4441    2     2
2019-01-06  01:10:00    4446    2     1
2019-01-06  01:40:00    4447    2     3
2019-01-06  01:50:00    4434    2     1
2019-01-06  02:20:00    4435    2     3
2019-01-06  02:30:00    4443    2     1
2019-01-06  02:40:00    4449    2     1
2019-01-06  02:50:00    4444    2     2
```

Is there a simple way of doing this? Not the best so any guidance would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I am just baffled on how `win` is calculated.

Comment: I just call the column win. 
i use 2 for win, 1 for draw/place, 0 for loss

Answer (score 0):

I see.  You are counting the rows *between* the wins.  Basically, you want to assign a group.  This group is the cumulative number of `2`s *on or after* that record.  Then, within each group, you can use `row_number()` or even aggregation in this case (because you know the last row of the group is "2"):

```
select date, max(time), 2 as win, count(*) as racestowin
from (select m.*,
             sum(case when m.win = 2 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by m.date order by m.time desc) as grouping
      from master m
     ) m
group by date, grouping;
```